# How to deploy Rails 4 with Capistrano 2 and precompile assets locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, asset-pipeline

Recently I upgraded an application from Rails 3 to Rails 4. In the deploy scripts I precompile the assets locally and then rsync them up to the server(s). In Rails 4 the asset pipeline now produces `manifest- < random > .json` instead of a `manifest.yml`. Since the manifest files are named differently, this adds multiple `manifest.json` files to the shared assets directory. The application then picks up the wrong manifest file, and serves old assets.

I have read about various issues related to this in some github pull request threads:

- https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/pull/412
- https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/210
- https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/pull/281

My options seem to be:

1. Don't share the asset directory.

   This would break old clients asking for old resources.
2. Switch to compiling assets on the servers.

   This would add complexity to the server.
3. Move the manifest file outside of the shared asset directory.

   I have since learned that this option was removed in Rails 4.

Are there other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the best answer after looking at the standard capistrano rails asset precompile task. I added a command to the local precompile task that moves the old asset manifest to the current release as asset_manifest.json. This leaves only one manifest when the new one is uploaded.

`run "mv -- #{shared_manifest_path.shellescape} #{current_path.to_s.shellescape}/assets_manifest#{File.extname(shared_manifest_path)}".compact`

Moving the manifest-.json to the current_dir as asset_manifest.json allows capistrano to restore the correct manifest file on rollback.